# Supplicating through the mind

Tags: dua

Is it permissible and sufficient to supplicate to Allah ﷻ inaudibly? Like for example wishing for good unto someone or asking for forgiveness but doing so with the mind or heart.

Comment: Allah know whatever is in mind and so you can always make dua in your mind, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hadith regarding something similar:

> Abu Musa Al-Ashari (ra) said:
> “We were with the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) on a military expedition. When we returned, we overlooked Al-Madinah, and the people were pronouncing the Takbīr, and they raised their voices with it. The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: ‘Verily, your Lord is not deaf nor absent, He is between you and between the heads of your mounts.’ Then he said: ‘O `Abdullah bin Qais, should I not inform you of a treasure from the treasures of Paradise: Lā ḥawla wa lā quwwata illā billāh (There is no might or power except by Allah).’”

Source for the above the hadith: https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3374

This hadith indicates that Allah hears all, as again indicated in this verse:

> Do they not see the birds above them with wings outspread and [sometimes] folded in? None holds them [aloft] except the Most Merciful. Indeed He is, of all things, Seeing. (Saheeh International, 67:19)

Source for the above verse: https://quran.com/67:19

Allah knows whatever is in your hearts, and he knows whatever you may be thinking. But it is better to make your supplication out loud because of verse from the Quran:

> Say, "Call upon Allāh or call upon the Most Merciful [ar-Raḥmān]. Whichever [name] you call - to Him belong the best names." And do not recite [too] loudly in your prayer or [too] quietly but seek between that an [intermediate] way. (Saheeh International, 17:110)

Source for the above verse: https://quran.com/17:110

And this from Muwatta Malik:

> Yahya related to me from Malik from Hisham ibn Urwa that his father said, "The following ayat was sent down about dua - 'And do not be loud in your prayer and do not be silent in it, but seek a way between these.' " (Sura 17 ayat 110)

Source for the above: https://sunnah.com/malik/15/41

So from this we know that we should obviously not be silent in our duas.

And Allah knows best.